# Schreibt man Ordnungszahlwörter ohne Substantiv groß?

Tags: spelling

> Ich bin in der fünften Klasse.
>   Ich bin auch in der fünften. *oder* Ich bin auch in der Fünften.

?

Answer (score 6):

In

> Ich bin in der fünften Klasse

schreibt man das Ordnungszahladjektiv eindeutig klein - Es hat ein "passendes" Substantiv dabei, das die Funktion des Objekts im Satz trägt.

In

> Seit ich in der Fünften bin, sehe ich meine Schwester kaum noch in den Pausen.

gibt es kein anderes Substantiv, das die Funktion des Objekts in diesem Satz übernehmen kann. Ein weiterer eindeutiger Hinweis auf ein *substantiviertes Adjektiv*, das nach §57 der [deutschen Rechtschreibregeln](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf) groß zu schreiben ist, ist die Existenz eines Artikels, der sich nur auf dieses substantivierte Adjektiv beziehen kann. Sollte sich innerhalb des Kontexts (von dem du uns leider nicht sehr viel geliefert hast) aber ein Substantiv befinden, auf das sich das Adjektiv beziehen könnte, wird wiederum klein geschrieben (§58):

> Die Kinder lernen Englisch von der ersten bis zur achten Klasse. Ich bin in der fünften.

Hier ist klar, dass sich das Adjektiv auf das Substantiv "Klasse" des vorhergehenden Satzes bezieht, und es muss deshalb klein geschrieben werden.

Comment: Danke. Beispiel: `Gehst du noch zu Schule? Ja, ich bin in der elften.` Hier ist für jeden, der weiß, dass es in Schulen Klassen gibt (und nur für den ist der Satz überhaupt verständlich), ebenso klar wie bei expliziter Nennung von "Klasse", dass sich das Adjektiv "elfte" auf das ausgelassene Substantiv "Klasse" bezieht. Es handelt sich m.E. also nicht um eine Substantivierung, sondern eine Ellipse. Die Beispiele in den von dir zitierten Regeln sind ja anders: "Er kam als Dritter dran." Hierzu gibt es keine gebräuchliche Form mit Substantiv. Zu "in der fünften" schon.

Comment: Nein. Dein Beispiel ist falsch. Steht "Ich bin in der Elften" alleine, ohne eine "Klasse" in der Nähe, schreibt man groß - auch wenn man sich die Klasse "denken kann".  Ich verstehe nicht, wie du dir die Regeln auslegst, aber sie sind an sich eindeutig. Und was ist an "Er kam als dritter Prüfling/Teilnehmer/Mann/Verurteilter/... dran" weniger "gebräuchlich" als an "fünfter Klasse"? Wie du sicher gesehen hast, kommt das Wort "gebräuchlich" in den Regeln gar nicht vor...